# Configuring holidays for Nagios

Tags: nagios

I had nagios configured to know that this was a holiday:

```
monday -1 may       00:00-24:00 ; Memorial Day (Last Monday in May)
```

As far as I can tell it didn't work on Monday because I received some alarms, no big deal, I can ignore those. But now I noticed that those alerts were not running today (June 1). I removed the line and now they're running again. This is straight out of the example timeperiods.cfg, but maybe the docs are incorrect.

Does anyone have a timeperiod config for Nagios that works for holidays like "last Monday in may" or "fourth Thursday in November"?

Comment: Sounds like you might have a timezone issue. Do all your other non-24x7 timeperiods work properly?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you look at the example in the distribution.....

```
 monday -1 may           00:00-00:00     ; Memorial Day (last Monday in May)
```

Notice that the start and end times are 0000!!

Comment: Seriously, WTF? If that's significant, couldn't it be an error? I'll give it a try thanks.

Comment: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/oncallrotation.html shows this with 24:00